# Не скачиваются данные после первого круга в цикле

Tags: c#

При первом круге в цикле for всё скачивается как надо, на следующих при скачивании появляется ошибка на получении ответа:

> System.Net.WebException: "Время ожидания операции истекло"

Запускал через Thread и BackgroudWorker результат один. Код функции скачивания:

```
private string Download(string url, string method = "GET", string data = null, CookieContainer cookie = null, UserAgent Agent = UserAgent.Browser)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            request.Method = method;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            if (Agent == UserAgent.Browser)
            {
                request.UserAgent = agentBrowser;
            }
            else if (Agent == UserAgent.SteamClient)
            {
                request.UserAgent = agentSteamClient;
            }
            if(method == "POST")
            {
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                request.GetRequestStream().Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data).Length);
                request.GetRequestStream().Close();
            }
            if(cookie != null)
            {
                request.CookieContainer = cookie;
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string val = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                return val;
            }
        }
```

Вот сам код запуска:

```
public void AccountRegistrationManagement()
        {
            if (TypeThreading == TYPETHREADING.SingleFlow)
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OnSingleThread));
                thread.IsBackground = false;
                thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                thread.Start();
            }
        }
 private void OnSingleThread()
        {
            TYPEERROR error = TYPEERROR.None;
            int count = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < lSteamLogin.Count; i++)
            {
                Start:
                string login = lSteamLogin[i];
                string pass = lSteamPassword[i];
                count += 1;
                if (count == 2) goto Finish;
                OnStartRegistering(login, pass);
                if(error == TYPEERROR.OK)
                {
                    count = -1;
                    goto Finish;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.MailEnded)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                    return;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.ProxyEnded)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                    if(isProxy == false)
                    {
                        goto Start;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.CookieNull)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                    if (isRetryAfterError) goto Start;
                    return;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.VerifyNull)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                    if (isRetryAfterError) goto Start;
                    return;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.BadSteamMail)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.BadCaptcha)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                    if (isRetryAfterError) goto Start;
                    return;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.SessionNull)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                    if (isRetryAfterError) goto Start;
                    return;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.SessionIDNull)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                    if (isRetryAfterError) goto Start;
                    return;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.MailNotConfirmed)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.BadSteam)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                }
                else if(error == TYPEERROR.BadPassword)
                {
                    if (isRetryAfterError == false) goto Finish;
                    return;
                }
                Finish:
                AddStatus("Переход к следующему аккаунту");
            }
```

UPD: вот и решение которое мне помогло: на скачивание картинки я добавлял куки, после того как убрал всё лишнее ошибок больше не было

Comment: `При первом круге в цикле for ....` у вас в коде нет цикла `for`

Comment: @tym32167 обновил код, добавил цикл

Comment: из вашего цикла метод `Download` не вызывается нигде, метод `AccountRegistrationManagement` не вызывается нигде - вы просто кидаете набор не связанных методов - вы сами то по ним можете хоть что то понять? Я - нет. Ознакомьтесь: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Вы про `break` и `continue` слышали что-нибудь?

Comment: @Bulson слышал, но здесь они мне не нужны. Когда будут нужны тогда и буду использовать.

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Как раз таки они вам очень нужны, даже необходимы, они избавят вас от использования `goto Start;` и `goto Finish;`, помогут писать чистый и ясный код.

Comment: @Bulson значит я не понял как я могу их применить у себя.